# Setting value to NULL as opposed to 'NULL'

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a function which adds varhcars and integers into a database row

```
public function addItem($id, $site, $price, $quantity, $condition, 
   $sellerName, $sellerRating, $sellerLocation, $description, $link){

   $q = "INSERT INTO tbl_items VALUES(
      '$id',
      '$site',
      $price, 
      $quantity, 
      '$condition',
      '$sellerName',
      $sellerRating,
     '$sellerLocation',
     '$description',
     '$link',
     ".time().")";

  return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);    
}
```

There may be situations where I may decide that I want to set a varchar value to NULL, but the problem is if I send the string NULL as a parameter it will always be treated as a string.

e.g.

```
addItem("id1", "site1", 100, NULL, "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL",);
```

How do I avoid NULL being treated a string in my query?

Comment: a PHP null will be converted to an empty string when you try to insert it into the query string. Since your code is using `'` everywhere, there is no way to insert an actual sql 'null' into that string, without redoing how you build the query string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy. **Don't quote it**, as `'NULL'` is always a string and `NULL` is .. well, NULL.

How? Use placeholders aka prepare statements.

This will take care of any quoting (as required) *and* prevent SQL injection attacks. Win.

See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) which contains information on writing safe queries and has examples for both mysqli and PDO approaches.

Comment: Ok I just skimmed through a few article on the web, what happens when I have a duplicate key and im using placeholders?

Comment: @mk_89 Same thing as without placeholders :) However, while I stand by my answer as the general solution, it is likely that the variables, e.g. $condition already contain the string value `NULL` (e.g. `$condition = "NULL"`). Make sure to address this as well.